# 802.1x authentication not working on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ethernet

I am not able to connect to my Ethernet(via LAN) which requires 802.1X authentication (tyoe PEAP (MSCHAPv2)) on my Ubuntu 14.04 in Dell Inspiron 14z. I had been able to connect in Ubuntu 13.04 LTS and on my Windows 8. Plz help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in the network manager: https://askubuntu.com/questions/461067/is-peap-tls-possible-for-wired-wireless-802-1x

The bug report can be seen here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1104476/comments/138

Basically, even if you don't set a CA Certificate, the Network Manager was trying to look for one.

I had to set the variable "system-ca-certs" to "false" manually in the file /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/name_of_your_network. You would add a line like this (or change it if it was "true"):

```
system-ca-certs=false
```

Comment: Set it where? Following the link, then following another link in a comment, I can see that it is probably in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/mynetwork`. But it would be good if you wrote it directly in your answer (and possibly linking to the original source)